# Use TypeScript custom transformer and project reference

Tags: typescript

I have a project that uses project reference and I also need to use custom transformer. However, project reference need to use tsc to realize the incremental compilation. But when using TSC, transformer cannot be applied.

What is the recommended solution here without re-implementing TSC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle use `createSolutionBuilderWithWatchHost`/`createSolutionBuilderWithWatch` APIs and invoke `getNextInvalidatedProject()` on every watch callback. Then check project type and invoke the `emit()` with custom transformers. Here's a relevant piece.

```
  if (proj && proj.kind === ts.InvalidatedProjectKind.Build) {
    progSource = proj;
    proj.emit(
      void 0,
      void 0,
      void 0,
      void 0,
      { after: [transformInjectStatementNumbers] });
  }
```

And you can pass `{ incremental: false }` for build options into `createSolutionBuilderWithWatch`.

Check [**the original post with more details**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62132983/140739) or directly to [gist](https://gist.github.com/mihailik/11369fd2b5e0603a14bc5d883d47dd6c) and [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@OlegMihailik/buildjs-tscreateSolutionBuilderWithWatch#index.js).

Comment: This doesn't keep the incremental feature of `tsc -b`

Comment: Ah I've updated that post with `solutionBuilder` use and forgot to patch this reply. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62132983/140739