# TypeScript custom transformers with ts.createWatchProgram

Tags: typescript

TypeScript has several high-level APIs to implement **watch/compile,**  for example:

- [**createWatchCompilerHost**( rootFiles, options, system, ... )](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0b38a9a2b03d3c651822bc2a20d381545384f0f5/src/compiler/watchPublic.ts#L196)
- [**createSolutionBuilderWithWatchHost**( system, ... )](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/177713ef45f7714c91af79246b8b5e2b6bd59128/src/compiler/tsbuildPublic.ts#L193)
- [**createSolutionBuilderWithWatch**( host, rootFiles, ... )](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/177713ef45f7714c91af79246b8b5e2b6bd59128/src/compiler/tsbuildPublic.ts#L212)

Can any of them be used with **custom transformers?**

A comment to [solutionBuilder.**getNextInvalidatedProject**()](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31432) mentions ability to pass transformers, but it cannot be used with watchers.

Basically, I need via API to run TypeScript compiler in `--watch` mode, but passing in my custom transformers. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better approach, more aligned with [solutionBuilder.**getNextInvalidatedProject()**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31432) recommendation.

When you call **solutionBuilder.getNextInvalidatedProject() .emit(...)** manually, you can pass in transformers. Invoking that API marks build as complete, meaning it won't emit again in its usual non-customised way.

You would invoke it both before the initial `build()` and from `WatchStatusReporter` callback.

That way you inject custom transformers, yet still retain built-in watching logic. See the proof-of-concept script below at work:

[image]

Here's full code, see also [**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/mihailik/11369fd2b5e0603a14bc5d883d47dd6c) and [**Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@OlegMihailik/buildjs-tscreateSolutionBuilderWithWatch#index.js).

```js
// @ts-check

var ts = require('typescript');

var tsconfig_json = JSON.stringify({
  compilerOptions: {
    outFile: __filename + '.out.js',
    allowJs: true,
    checkJs: true,
    target: 'es3'
  },
  files: [__filename]
}, null, 2);

var s = {
  delete: 3
};

/** @type {import('typescript').System} */
var sysOverride = {};
for (var k in ts.sys) { sysOverride[k] = ts.sys[k]; }
sysOverride.readFile = function (file) {
  if (ts.sys.resolvePath(file) === ts.sys.resolvePath(__dirname + '/tsconfig.json')) {
    // console.log('readFile(', file, ') -> overridden tsconfig_json');
    return tsconfig_json;
  }
  else {
    var result = ts.sys.readFile(file);
    // if (!/node_modules/.test(file))
    //   console.log('readFile(', file, ') -> ' + (typeof result === 'string' ? '"' + result.length + '"' : typeof result));
    return result;
  }
};
sysOverride.writeFile = function (file, content) {
  console.log('  sys.writeFile(', file, ', [', content.length, '])');
  ts.sys.writeFile(file, content);
};

var host = ts.createSolutionBuilderWithWatchHost(
  sysOverride,
  void 0,
  reportDiag,
  reportDiag,
  reportWatch);

var buildStart = Date.now();

var solutionBuilder = ts.createSolutionBuilderWithWatch(
  host,
  [__dirname],
  { incremental: false }, {});

initiateFirstBuild();


function initiateFirstBuild() {
  var firstBuild = solutionBuilder.getNextInvalidatedProject();
  if (firstBuild) {
    buildStart = Date.now();
    startBuild(firstBuild);
  }

  solutionBuilder.build();
}

/**
 * @param {import('typescript').InvalidatedProject<import('typescript').EmitAndSemanticDiagnosticsBuilderProgram>} proj
 * @param {import('typescript').Diagnostic=} watchDiag 
 */
function startBuild(proj, watchDiag) {
  ts.sys.write(
    '\x1b[93m ' + (ts.InvalidatedProjectKind[proj.kind] + '          ').slice(0, 10) + '\x1b[0m' +
    (watchDiag ? '' : '\n'));

  if (watchDiag) reportDiag(watchDiag);

  buildStart = Date.now();

  if (proj && proj.kind === ts.InvalidatedProjectKind.Build) {
    progSource = proj;
    proj.emit(
      void 0,
      void 0,
      void 0,
      void 0,
      { after: [transformInjectStatementNumbers] });
  }

}


function completeBuild(watchDiag) {
  ts.sys.write('\x1b[90m ' + (((Date.now() - buildStart) / 1000) + 's        ').slice(0, 10) + '\x1b[0m');
  if (watchDiag) reportDiag(watchDiag);
}

/** @type {import('typescript').FormatDiagnosticsHost} */
var diagHost;
/** @param {import('typescript').Diagnostic} diag */
function reportDiag(diag) {
  if (!diagHost) {
    diagHost = {
      getCanonicalFileName: function (fileName) {
        return ts.sys.resolvePath(fileName)
      },
      getCurrentDirectory: function () {
        return ts.sys.getCurrentDirectory();
      },
      getNewLine: function () {
        return ts.sys.newLine;
      }
    };
  }

  var output = ts.sys.writeOutputIsTTY && ts.sys.writeOutputIsTTY() ?
    ts.formatDiagnosticsWithColorAndContext([diag], diagHost) :
    ts.formatDiagnostic(diag, diagHost);

  output = output.replace(/^[\r\n]+/, '').replace(/[\r\n]+$/, '');

  ts.sys.write(output + '\n');
}

/** @param {import('typescript').Diagnostic} diag */
function reportWatch(diag) {
  var proj = solutionBuilder.getNextInvalidatedProject();
  if (proj && /** @type {*} */(proj).getProgram) {
    progSource = /** @type {*} */(proj);
  }

  if (proj)
    startBuild(proj, diag);
  else
    completeBuild(diag);
}


/** @type {{ getProgram(): import('typescript').Program }} */
var progSource;
/** @type {import('typescript').TypeChecker} */
var checker;
/** @param {import('typescript').TransformationContext} context */
function transformInjectStatementNumbers(context) {
  checker = progSource.getProgram().getTypeChecker();
  return transformFile;

  function transformFile(sourceFile) {
    console.log('   transforming(', sourceFile.fileName, ')...');
    return ts.updateSourceFileNode(
      sourceFile,
      sourceFile.statements.map(decorateStatementWithComplexityAndType));
  }
}

/**
 * @param {import('typescript').Statement} statement 
 */
function decorateStatementWithComplexityAndType(statement) {
  var nodeCount = 0;
  var type;
  ts.forEachChild(statement, visitStatementChild);

  return ts.addSyntheticLeadingComment(
    statement, ts.SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia,
    ' INJECTED >> complexity: ' + nodeCount +
    (!type ? '' : ' : ' + checker.typeToString(type)));

  /**
   * @param {import('typescript').Node} child 
   */
  function visitStatementChild(child) {
    nodeCount++;
    if (!type) type = checker.getTypeAtLocation(child);
    if (type.getFlags() === ts.TypeFlags.Any) type = null;
    ts.forEachChild(child, visitStatementChild);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: refer to a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62132983/140739) with `createSolutionBuilderWithWatchHost`**

It can be done by intercepting `createProgram` and overriding its `emit` method.

Here is a POC script, with recording. The custom transform there decorates every top-level statement with AST stats/types.

[image: running watch compilation with a custom transform]

Repl.IT        https://repl.it/@OlegMihailik/custom-transformers-tscreateWatchProgram#index.js
GitHub gist https://gist.github.com/mihailik/11369fd2b5e0603a14bc5d883d47dd6c/6a505999a8bfcc25bbcac8befd6c4060591bf4e7

```js
var ts = require('typescript');
var diagReport = ts.createBuilderStatusReporter(ts.sys, ts.sys.writeOutputIsTTY && ts.sys.writeOutputIsTTY());

var host = ts.createWatchCompilerHost(
  [__filename],
  { allowJs: true, checkJs: true, outFile: __filename + '.out.js' },
  ts.sys,
  createAndPatchProgram,
  void 0,
  reportWatch);

var buildStart = Date.now();

ts.createWatchProgram(host);

function reportWatch(diag, newLine, options, errorCount) {
  ts.sys.write(typeof errorCount === 'number' ?
    '\x1b[90m ' + (((Date.now() - buildStart) / 1000) + 's        ').slice(0, 10) + '\x1b[0m' :
    'WATCH DIAG ');
  diagReport(diag);

  if (typeof errorCount !== 'number') buildStart = Date.now();
}

var prog;
function createAndPatchProgram() {
  prog = ts.createEmitAndSemanticDiagnosticsBuilderProgram.apply(ts, arguments);
  prog.__oldEmit = prog.emit;
  prog.emit = overrideEmit;
  return prog;
}

function overrideEmit(targetSourceFile, writeFile, cancellationToken, emitOnlyDtsFiles, customTransformers) {
  return this.__oldEmit(
    targetSourceFile,
    writeFile,
    cancellationToken,
    emitOnlyDtsFiles,
    { after: [transformInjectStatementNumbers] }
  );
}

var checker;
/** @param {import('typescript').TransformationContext} context */
function transformInjectStatementNumbers(context) {
  checker = prog.getProgram().getTypeChecker();
  return transformFile;

  function transformFile(sourceFile) {
    return ts.updateSourceFileNode(
      sourceFile,
      sourceFile.statements.map(decorateStatementWithComplexityAndType));
  }
}

function decorateStatementWithComplexityAndType(statement) {
  var nodeCount = 0;
  var type;
  ts.forEachChild(statement, visitStatementChild);

  return ts.addSyntheticLeadingComment(
    statement, ts.SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia,
    ' complexity: ' + nodeCount +
    (!type ? '' : ' : ' + checker.typeToString(type)));

  function visitStatementChild(child) {
    nodeCount++;
    if (!type) type = checker.getTypeAtLocation(child);
    if (type.getFlags() === ts.TypeFlags.Any) type = null;
    ts.forEachChild(child, visitStatementChild);
  }
}
```